# Cannot set headers on supertest

Tags: node.js, express, axios, supertest

```
test('a valid blog can be added', async () => {

  const newBlog = {
    title: "Canonical string reduction",
    author: "Edsger W. Dijkstra",
    url: "http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD808.html",
    likes: 12
  }

  await api
  .post("/api/blogs")
  .send(newBlog)
  .set("Authorization",`bearer xxxxxxxx`)
  .set("Accept","application/json")
  .expect(201)



const blogsAtEnd = await helper.blogsInDb()
expect(blogsAtEnd).toHaveLength(initialBlogs.length + 1)

const title = blogsAtEnd.map(r => r.title)
expect(title).toContain('Canonical string reduction')
})
```

The following test should return a successful 201 created but returns a 401 'not authorized'.

The same blog being posted on Postman with the same token + header works with a 201, but the test does not. I am guessing it is because await.set(Authorization...) is not working properly.

Does anyone know why this is?

Here is the code for the route:

```
blogsRouter.post('/', async (request, response, next) => {
    const body = request.body

    const token = getTokenFrom(request)
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
    if (!decodedToken.id) {
      return response.status(401).json({ error: 'token missing or invalid' })
    }
    const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)
  
  if (body.title === undefined) {
    return response.status(400).json({ error: 'content missing' })
  }

  if (body.author === undefined) {
    return response.status(400).json({ error: 'content missing' })
  }


  const newblog = new Blog({
    title: body.title,
    author: body.author,
    url: body.url,
    user: user._id
  })

    const savedBlog = await newblog.save()
    user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(savedBlog._id)
    await user.save()

    response.json(savedBlog)

  })
```

Comment: The `Authorization` header should be `Bearer xxxxxxxx`, not `bearer xxxxxxxx`.

Comment: Thanks, but makes no difference

Comment: have same error

Comment: Try calling set method before send?